# Display expression of layer if geometries intersect in QGIS

Tags: qgis, intersection, expression, values

I'd like to display the value of a layer (polygon with parcels) only in case a line (f.e. a river) intersects, crosses or touches the polygon of the parcel by using the expression dialog... but I miserably fail. Any ideas? :)

Comment: What do you mean by "display the value"? Do you mean you want to only turn on labels for parcels which intersect a river?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. In my case, i only want to display the value of the attribute-table of the parcel (f.e. parcel-number) if the river is crossing the parcel. Míght be helpful if you have many little parcels surrounding the parcels of concern. 
Hope my English isn't too bad and you get what i am trying to achieve :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be achieved by using `Rule-based labeling` on your polygon layer, with the following expression:

```sql
overlay_intersects('line')
```

*where 'line' is the name of your line layer*

Steps:

- Choose `Rule-based Labeling` for your polygon layer (1)
- Add a new rule by clicking the plus icon (2)
- Double-click the new rule to configure it
- Click the `Edit expression` button (3)
- Enter the expression in the editor (4)
- Click <kbd>Ok</kbd>
- Configure the field or value you want to display (5)

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Result:

[image]

How it works:

The expression returns `true` for those features in the polygon layer that intersect features in the line layer. This is used by the rule to filter features that are given a label.

You can add extra parameters to `overlay_intersects`, but this is the most basic usage. See the Help panel in the expression editor for advanced usage.

Comment: Great answer! Nice

Comment: Wow, thank you very much Matt for the very detailed and great answer!
This will help with the problem i was exactly looking for. 

For those who like, please let me know if there is a python expression to do exactly that, or if it is even possible. I was busting my brain with several ideas, but without success... 

But as I said. Problem solved! Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Marek as the answer solved your problem, you should accept it: hit the checkmark icon next to it, see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Somewhat inspired by your ever-thorough answers, @Babel :)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I was looking for a way how to checkmark. now you solved a second question, that was going through my mind :)